# Where does the absolute value sign come from for this integral on Peskin&Schroeder page 14?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, integration

On page 14 of Peskin&Schroeder, the authors are calculating the amplitute of a free particle propagating between states $|\vec{x_0}\rangle$ and $|\vec{x}\rangle$ using relativistic quantum mechanics of a particle.

The integral of interest reads:
$$\langle\vec{x}|e^{-i\sqrt{\vec{p}^2+m^2}}|\vec{x}_0\rangle=\int\frac{d^3\vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3}e^{-it\sqrt{\vec{p}^2+m^2}}e^{i\vec{p}\cdot(\vec{x}-\vec{x}_0)}.$$

The result is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi^2|\vec{x}-\vec{x}_0|}\int^{\infty}_0dp~p\sin(p|\vec{x}-\vec{x}_0|)e^{-it\sqrt{p^2+m^2}}\tag{1}\label{1}$$
which is then evaluated in terms of Bessel function.

I am able to derive equation $\ref{1}$ except for the **absolute value sign** put on $|\vec{x}-\vec{x}_0|$ and I cannot think of why we would ever need it. Could someone help?

Comment: It's not an absolute value sign, it is the *length* of the vector $x-x_0$. As $p$ is a scalar, if you omitted the $|\ldots|$ you would be taking the sine of a vector.

Comment: More on [P&S p. 14](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=peski*+14).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per comment, it's not an absolute value sign, it is the length of the vector ${\bf x}−{\bf x_0}$. You can see this (for instance) by noticing you are taking a dot product in the exponent.

Explicitely, first take spherical coordinates transformation
$$\int\frac{d^3\vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3}e^{-it\sqrt{\vec{p}^2+m^2}}e^{i\vec{p}\cdot(\vec{x}-\vec{x}_0)} = \int d\phi\int\frac{p^2\sin\theta d\theta dp}{(2\pi)^3}e^{-it\sqrt{p^2+m^2}}e^{ip|\vec{x}-\vec{x}_0|cos\theta}$$
where I used ${\bf x}\cdot {\bf y} = xy\cos\theta$, the typical definition of the dot product in real space, where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors. Then, we take [$\theta$ integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%20%20sin%28x%29e%5E%28i*y*cos%28x%29%29%20dx%20from%200%20to%20pi) (which is from $0$ to $\pi$ here, as are regular spherical coordenates, since we are matching the definition of $\theta$ with that of the angle between the vectors) we get

$$\int d\phi\int\frac{p^2 dp}{(2\pi)^3p|\vec{x}-\vec{x}_0|}e^{-it\sqrt{p^2+m^2}}\sin({p|\vec{x}-\vec{x}_0|})$$

For completion now, take $\phi$ integral (amounts to a $2\pi$) and simplify
$$\int\frac{p dp}{(2\pi)^2|\vec{x}-\vec{x}_0|}e^{-it\sqrt{p^2+m^2}}\sin({p|\vec{x}-\vec{x}_0|})$$
where we obtain what you get.